# Flyout submenu with we.sitemap and a repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I've search and found some great examples of flyout menus but here is what I'm facing. In this existing site I want to add a dropdown or flyout menu to one of the item but looking at it, it seems rather challenging. The following is involved in this. A web.sitemap file with several sitemap nodes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
 <siteMapNode url="/" title=""  description=""  roles="*">
  <siteMapNode url="default.aspx" title="Home"  description="Welcome page"  />
  <siteMapNode url="events.aspx" title="Events"  description="Events"  />
  <siteMapNode url="news.aspx" title="News"  description="News"  />
  <siteMapNode url="photos.aspx" title="Photos"  description="Photo album"  />
  <siteMapNode url="contact.aspx" title="Contact"  description="Contact us"  />
 </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Then in the master file there is this:

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="false" />
    <asp:Repeater ID="TopNavRepeat" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <ul>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <li>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>'
                    ToolTip='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            </li>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </ul>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

What I want to do is add dropdown of several submenu items that will going to different pages from the contacts node. How can I do this and can someone point me to a sample (please)?

Thanks,

Risho

Answer (score 0):

You can add subitems continually:

```
<siteMapNode url="contact.aspx" title="Contact"  description="Contact us">
  <siteMapNode url="contact.aspx?dept=Sales" title="Contact Sales" description="Contact us" />
  <siteMapNode url="contact.aspx?dept=Tech" title="Contact Technical Support" description="Contact us" />
</siteMapNode>
```

Comment: Thanks for you post, but pehaps I'm missing something else becuase it didn't work.

Comment: OK, then what are you using for the menu?  How is that setup?  Can you post some of that markup/code?